# Manipulate Bloom to fit faces or into any shape?

Tags: rendering, materials, color, emission

I would like to fill up these empty faces with bloom as per this screenshot.

[image]

How do I do so? Here is my corresponding blender file:

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to select the object, fill the faces, then give it the same material as the one that is glowing, what difficulty have you met?

Comment: I want that orange glow/bloom to fill up the faces. Unfortunately, when I did, the white emission was there instead.

Examples of what I really want: 
https://ibb.co/SX7Nmz5
 
https://ibb.co/JdNdNhg

Comment: The bloom settings are in the render properties. Try increasing the radius. Bear in mind it's a screen space effect so it might not look the same depending on viewing angle and location

Comment: @FrancisMikeNathan Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

When I open your file, it's already in *Edit Mode* on the object you want to fill. So in this case the easiest way is:

1. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill everything (fortunately it works that simple with this geometry).
3. There could be errors in face orientation, so press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*.
4. Give the object the same (or a different if needed?) glowing material as the other object.

Comment: What I want is for that orange bloom to fill up those empty faces, as I want that orange bloom to be a notable part of that mesh shape

Comment: @FrancisMikeNathan Okay, that is not really clear in your question - bloom is an overlaid post effect and cannot fill any faces. If you want the bloom to extend so far that it covers the empty faces, change the settings. If this is not producing the correct result (since the bloom comes from the inner object which does not cover the shape of the outer object, then you have to fill the faces and give them an emissive object with bloom like I described in my answer - if you don't want white emission, give it a new material with orange emission.

Comment: And if you have no idea how to create materials with different colors and change them on the objects etc. then I would highly recommend you watch some basic tutorials about materials, shading and textures in Blender.